# Looping through Pandas data frame for a calculation based off the row values in two different list

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have been able to get the calculation to work but now I am having trouble appending the results back into the data frame e3. You can see from the picture that the values are printing out.

```
brand_list = list(e3["Brand Name"])
product_segment_list = list(e3['Product Segment'])

# Create a list of tuples: data
data = list(zip(brand_list, product_segment_list))

for i in data:
    step1 = e3.loc[(e3['Brand Name']==i[0]) & (e3['Product Segment']==i[1])]
    Delta_Price = (step1['Price'].diff(1).div(step1['Price'].shift(1),axis=0).mul(100.0))
    print(Delta_Price)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's easier to use groupby. In each loop 'r' will be just the grouped rows from e3 dataframe from each category and i an index.

```
new_df = []
for i,r in e3.groupby(['Brand Name','Product Segment']):
    price_num = r["Price"].diff(1).values
    price_den = r["Price"].shift(1).values
    r['Price Delta'] = price_num/price_den
    new_df.append(r)
e3_ = pd.concat(new_df, axis = 1)
```